# Can't update macOS to 12.6.1. Neither from Software Update, nor from command line

Tags: macos

I've been trying to update OSX Monterey to 12.6.1. In Software Update GUI I had "*Failed to prepare the software update. Please try again.*"

So I tried doing it in command line to see if the response is going to be more readable. I used this command:

```
sudo softwareupdate -i "macOS Monterey 12.6.1-21G217" -R
```

And the response is like this:

```
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
Downloading macOS Monterey 12.6.1
Downloading: 100.00%
Failed to download & prepare update: Error Domain=SUOSUErrorDomain Code=201 "Failed to >prepare the software update. Please try again." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=An error occurred while downloading the selected updates. Please check your internet connection and try again., NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to prepare the software update. Please try again., NSUnderlyingError=0x6000011299b0 {Error Domain=SUMacControllerError Code=7740 "[SUMacControllerErrorPrepareFailed=7740] Failed to perform Prepare operation: [MobileSoftwareUpdateErrorDomain(MSU):MSU_ERR_PREPARE_FAILURE(16)]" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to prepare the software update. Please try again., SUMacControllerErrorIndicationsMask=0, NSDebugDescription=[SUMacControllerErrorPrepareFailed=7740] Failed to perform Prepare operation: [MobileSoftwareUpdateErrorDomain(MSU):MSU_ERR_PREPARE_FAILURE(16)], NSUnderlyingError=0x600001129980 {Error Domain=MobileSoftwareUpdateErrorDomain Code=16 "Could not find supported personalization variant in build manifest" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Could not find supported personalization variant in build manifest, target_update=21G217}}}}}
```

Comment: The bit about not finding a personalization in the build manifest suggests this update might not apply to your machine for some reason. Exactly what model of Mac is this on? Also, have you been running developer betas?

Comment: & what OS is it currently running?

Comment: Macbook pro 15-inch, 2019, 2.3ghz i9 with Radeon Vega 20 4gb.

Comment: @Tetsujin currently running OSX 12.3.1. Never been on beta